# Executing multiple statements in if-else without nullpointer exception

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to dig a little deeper into clojure and functional programming.

At some point of my code I have a `(def server (spawn-server))`. Now I want a short function for the REPL to check the state of this socket.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
(defn status []
  (if server 
    (
      (println "server is up and running")
      (println "connections:" (connection-count server)) 
     )    
    (println "server is down")))
```

If server is nil, everything works fine, but this is the output on the REPL if the server is running:

```
=> (status)
server is up and running
connections: 0
#<CompilerException java.lang.NullPointerException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)>
```

I'm not really sure if I see the problem, but I can't figure out how this should work :-)
What I have here is this:

```
((println "foo")(println "foo"))
```

which will be evaluated to `(nil nil)` which results in the NullPointerException ?

Usally I wouldn't use the outer parentheses but how can I create some kind of "block" statement for the if-condition. If I don't use them, the second println will be used as else.

What would work is the usage of let as some kind of "block"-statement:

```
(let [] 
  (println "server is up and running"),
  (println "connections:" (connection-count server)) )
```

But I'm not really sure if this the "right" solution?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use `do`:

```
(defn status []
  (if server 
    (do
      (println "server is up and running")
      (println "connections:" (connection-count server)))    
    (println "server is down")))
```

In Lisps, generally, you can't just add parens for grouping.

```
((println "foo") (println "foo"))
```

Here, the return value of the first `(println "foo")` will be tried to be called (as a function), with the return value of the second as an argument. Those are very basic evaluation rules, so I suggest that you hit some introductory books or documentation about Clojure or Lisps in general.

From the [evaluation](http://clojure.org/evaluation) section of the [Clojure homepage](http://clojure.org):

> Non-empty Lists are considered calls
>   to either special forms, macros, or
>   functions. A call has the form
>   (operator operands*).

Macros or special forms may "break" this rule.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I searched for.

Comment: Why the null pointer exception after all these years? this is so unfriendly ;-)

Comment: @matanster I don't know much about the reasons, but I agree that Clojure's error messages aren't the best.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but to specifically explain the null pointer exception, it is because the first println returns nil. The parenthesis after the `if` says "evaluate the first element in this list as a function". Because the first element evaluates to nil it throws the exception. Not that obvious, but a null pointer exception in Clojure is often becuase you tried to execute nil as function.

Comment: @ianjs Yes, that's correct, and the answer basically says the same.  ("[T]he return value of the first (println "foo") will be tried to be called (as a function), with the return value of the second as an argument".) If you're answering to @matanster 's comment, however, I think his point was that the error message is not very intuitive – especially for beginners. CCL, for example, says: `Error: Car of ((PRINC "foo") (PRINC "foo")) is not a function name or lambda-expression.` Much better, isn't it? Clojure's error message feels rather low-level for such a high-level language, IMO.